# Merge two xml files from two memory streams using linq and print the new file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

--edit
I will worry about memory stream later, how do I combined the strings first and print the output?
--edit

string1 xml

```xml
<study-groups>
  <study-group>
    <name></name>
    <uuid></uuid>
    <href></href>
  </study-group>
</study-groups>
```

xml string2

```xml
<studies>
 <study>
    <name>someValue</name>
    <uuid>someValue</uuid>
    <href>someValue</href>
    <parent-uuid>someValue</parent-uuid>
    <created-at>2015-08-12T17:51:03Z</created-at>
    <updated-at>2016-06-18T05:53:01Z</updated-at>
  </study>
  <study>
    <name></name>
    <uuid></uuid>
    <href></href>
    <parent-uuid></parent-uuid>
    <created-at>2015-08-12T17:51:03Z</created-at>
    <updated-at>2016-06-18T05:53:01Z</updated-at>
  </study>
</studies>
```

I am looping through API HTTP requests and saving the output xml to a string and to a memory stream.
the first foreach loop produces a single xml file.
in my second for each loop, it returns multiple files.
I want to join string1 and string2 to create string 3 without duplicates and pass string 3 into the third 4 each loop.

```cs
var xml1 = XDocument.Parse(string1);
var xml2 = XDocument.Parse(string2);


//Combine and remove duplicates
var string3 = xml1.Descendants("study-groups")
    .Union(xml2.Descendants("studies"));

Console.WriteLine("---------------------string 3---------------------------");
Console.WriteLine(string3.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("---------------------string 3---------------------------");

//Combine and keep duplicates
var combinedWithDups = xml1.Descendants("study-groups")
    .Concat(xml2.Descendants("studies"));

foreach (var i in combinedUnique)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------combinednodups---------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------combinednodups---------------------------");
}
```

but my output keeps coming out as:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+UnionIterator2`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]
```

Comment: Did you by accident delete some of the code? You mention several loops and variables we can't see.

Comment: I figured the other for each loops dont matter just the being able to compare the two files and return the query to a string would be enough to know and be able to repeat subsequently.

Comment: Could you give some example input and what you expect as output?

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question to include the xml strings in question.

Comment: You will not have a "Well Formed XML".  A Well Formed XML has only one Root Tag.  Just merging two XML you will have an array of two root tags.  The XML specification allows for an array of root tags but some software gives warning when this occurs.

Comment: I did end up running into the issue in the nested foreach loop and it doesnt want to parse the multi root element xml file . how could i load it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is simply the output, it's because calling `ToString()` on an `IEnumerable` (like most types) will simply print the name of the type.

Instead you could do:

```cs
// Join each element in the IEnumerable with a line break
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, string3));
```

This will produce the following with your example input:

```xml
<study-groups>
  <study-group>
    <name></name>
    <uuid></uuid>
    <href></href>
  </study-group>
</study-groups>
<studies>
  <study>
    <name>someValue</name>
    <uuid>someValue</uuid>
    <href>someValue</href>
    <parent-uuid>someValue</parent-uuid>
    <created-at>2015-08-12T17:51:03Z</created-at>
    <updated-at>2016-06-18T05:53:01Z</updated-at>
  </study>
  <study>
    <name></name>
    <uuid></uuid>
    <href></href>
    <parent-uuid></parent-uuid>
    <created-at>2015-08-12T17:51:03Z</created-at>
    <updated-at>2016-06-18T05:53:01Z</updated-at>
  </study>
</studies>
```

However, if that's all you want, there's no need for using an `XDocument`. You can simply concatenate the two strings:

```cs
var string3 = string1 + Environment.NewLine + string2;
Console.WriteLine(string3);
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this was the answer I needed.